# Нужно найти библиотеку для Datepicker'a

Tags: jquery, datepicker

[На этой странице](https://www.iaai.com/Auctions/AuctionSingleDateView.aspx) размещена секция с 2 кнопками "Сегодня" и "завтра", по центру скролл с выбором дат и слева датепикер. Не могу найти данную библиотеку, где можно найти её или может кто-нибудь встречал?

Comment: библиотеку `jquery datepicker` ? можешь сделать так `<inpu type="date" />`

Comment: то что вы показали это кастомный а не дефолтный плагин `jquery` стили поменяли под свои нужды

Comment: <inpuе type="date" /> - выдаёт просто поле для ввода даты, без пикера.
Еще с datepicker можно разобраться и сделать, а вот кнопки и особенно центральная часть, как она делается?

Comment: нет `datepicker` то же дает, внимательно посмотри, а то что ты хочешь из этого сайта, это кастомный стиль

Comment: ладно, тут согласен))
так а как центральную часть сделать?

Comment: Ты про то что с лева и с права со стрелками да?

Comment: да, про центральную

Comment: Это просто простой скроллбар

Comment: а где можно найти что-то похожее?

Comment: Не могу так с ходу сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> то что вы показали это кастомный а не дефолтный плагин jquery стили поменяли под свои нужды